# Alternatives to Object-Oriented Programming?

Tags: oop, programming-languages, paradigms

OOP is probably the most used programming paradigm in today’s software design. My question is – what other paradigm(s) **can compete with it and can stand in the place of OOP**? To clarify that question, I’m not asking about what other paradigms there are. There are many of them, but I’d like to know which one…

- Has been used in practice, not only in theory.
- *Can compete with OOP*, so it can be used in a large project with a minimum of pain.
- Can be used to develop a desktop app with business logic, databases, and so on.
- Is not used alongside OOP, but as a replacement for OOP.

And if there is any, what are the pros/cons of it, why it is better/worse than OOP, what languages are the best to use it, what about using it in popular languages, has it any design patterns, and can it totally replace OOP?

Comment: @Justin Ardini: I know there are many, but which one can compete with oop? @Tobiasopdenbrouw & Macros: Ok, changed.

Comment: OOP is popular because it is popular, if you don't swallow the OOP koolaid you'll not have any projects to work on...

Comment: Data Oriented programming is easier, where you care about object collections and their relationships rather than single objects, where the "db object" methods provide encapsulation.  JSON and sexpressions sweeten   SQL, CSS, HTML, Excel, shell scripts are popular and useful, but "programming" means OOP or procedural.  OOP is thanked for maintainable of Python/JavaScript programs despite OOP being 20% of code.  Closures & JSON can be used 90% of the time in place of Objects and are simpler and easier to use.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

[Functional programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming) is another programming paradigm that is popular, mostly in academics. The best example of a functional programming language is [Haskell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haskell_(programming_language)) and [Standard ML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ML_programming_language).

The fundamental difference between functional programming and object oriented programming is that you are programming in the sense of **data flow** instead of **control flow**. See the presentation [Taming Effects with Functional Programming](http://www.infoq.com/presentations/Taming-Effect-Simon-Peyton-Jones) by *Simon Peyton-Jones* for a good introduction.

A good example of functional programming used in the industry is [Erlang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erlang_(programming_language)). It is mostly used in telecommunication, distributed and fault tolerant systems. See the presentation [Erlang - Software for a concurrent World](http://www.infoq.com/presentations/erlang-software-for-a-concurrent-world) by *Joe Armstrong*.

There are also newer functional programming languages that combine functional programming with OOP. Two good examples are [F#](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F_Sharp_(programming_language)) for the .NET platform and [Scala](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scala_(programming_language)) for the Java platform; they can often use existing libraries on the platform written in other languages.

The trend of new programming languages now is [Multi-paradigm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programming_paradigm), where multiple paradigms like object oriented programming and functional programming are combined in the same language.

Comment: Can functional programming replace oop or is it used with oop? Are there any real world examples of apps written in this paradigm? What about design patterns?

Comment: Scala aims to integrate features of object-oriented and functional languages.

Comment: Good answer, yet I think that functional programming and object-oriented programming are not two sides of a medal, they can perfectly coexist (as you mentioned). It's more like this: Procedural VS Object-oriented, Imperative VS Functional. Lisp is a popular procedural functional language, Java is an object-oriented imperative language.

Comment: @ventr1s: Yes, functional programming *can* replace OOP but it is most likely to be used together with OOP in languages like Scala and F#.

Comment: @ventr1s: A good example of functional programming in the industry is the distributed NoSQL database RIAK written in Erlang. http://riak.basho.com

Comment: @ventr1s: See this question about functional programming and design patterns: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/327955/does-functional-programming-replace-gof-design-patterns

Answer (score 13):

Procedural processing was everything before OOP turned up, has produced some large real world applications (in fact, most of them originally) and many operating systems.

It can certainly be used in large scale products with a minimum of pain, and a maximum of performance

Comment: Yeah, and countless metrics studies have shown it runs out of gas at around 150K LOC. Look at the Windows SDK circa time of Petzold for a treatise in how Structured Programming disintegrates under complexity loads: functions with 8 arguments, 2 are structs with 6-10 members. Pushing data in and out of every unit of computation eventually just doesn't work.

Comment: OK but - how many applications get this big? The problem with OOP is it's extremely complicated to understand, and designed for vast applications - but is the default even for small ones. This has the opposite effect of over complicating the smaller app un-necessarily.

Comment: Object oriented programming sometimes causes applications to be longer because of the need for constructors, and long getter/setter methods.  These early procedural languages like C didn't have support for Meta-programming, no system of polymorphism, closures, or easy syntax for JSON/general data representation.  C didn't even support for optional arguments.  Monads and Macros can be used to build powerful embedded Domain Specific Languages.

Comment: Functions with 8 arguments - ever heard of default arguments?  What about procedural + first class support for HashTables + closures like JavaScript, Python, etc...?  They have many of the advantages of OOP without as much code.

Answer (score 12):

First of all please note that many of the programming languages currently in use (especially "higher level languages") are **multi-paradigm**. That means you are never building programs which are purely OOP (except if you use Smalltalk or Eiffel to build your big projects maybe).

Have a look at **PHP** for instance:

- Has many elements of OOP (since version 5)
- Was mostly procedural before
- Has elements of declarative programming (e.g. the array functions)
- Implemented many elements of functional programming (since version 5.4)

Basically PHP is gluing a lot of different paradigms together (and is a "glue language" itself).

Also Java implements a lot of concepts which are not from the Object-Oriented paradigm (e.g. from functional programming).

Have a look on the list of programming languages by type in Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_programming_languages_by_type#Imperative_languages (not 100% accurate).

**Functional programming (subset of declerative programming)**

- Wideley used in practice (it became part of glued languages like *PHP*, also *Java* and many others have implemented concepts of functional programming)
- Many ideas originate in LISP which is definitely worth a look
- You can build whole applications e.g. with Haskell therefore it can "replace" OOP

**Procedural programming**

- C (as a mostly procedural language) is still one of the most widely used languages
- Many modern glue-languages were procedural in the beginning
- Still many programs are mostly procedural (so if you want it can "replace" OOP)

**Logical programming**

- Most prominent example is Prolog. This is used for specific tasks that benefit from rule-based logical queries
- Can not "replace" OOP in terms of building a large project but may replace it in other terms

**Declarative / Domain-specific languages in general**

- Using SQL in your projects? Then they are not purely OOP, SQL is essentially declarative.
- Many domain-specific languages (like CSS) are declarative

**Imperative programming in general**

- Tons of applications are not "object-oriented" but simply written in imperative style (e.g. assembly)
- Look here for a great thread: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/117092/whats-the-difference-between-imperative-procedural-and-structured-programming

This list is not complete it shall just give an idea. Just note that you usually are using a lot of different paradigms when writing a big application and even each language you are using is implementing multiple paradigms.

OOP is usually considered a good choice for structuring large, complex relationships when modelling data. It is not always the paradigm to go with for many other tasks.

Comment: I think that this is the best answer.

Answer (score 4):

Vector Relational Data Modeling is used to create executable information models with domain relevant semantics within the Global Information Network Architecture, a network resident model broker.

Comment: Read this 5 times fast xD

Answer (score 1):

FP - Functional Programming is an extremely popular programming paradigm that has been around for a very long time and has, in more recent years, started becoming more and more prominent.  FP favors immutability over mutability, recursion, and functions with no side effects.  Some examples of popular fp languages are Erlang, Scala, F#, Haskell and Lisp (among others).

Answer (score -9):

There are no paradigms currently that can genuinely replace OOP. The issue with (benefit of) OOP is that it does a vast amount of work for you- automatically releasing resources, validating data, etc, and it makes it easy to validate code- not to mention that the vast majority of the world's existing libraries are written in an OOP language like C++, C# or Java. The reality of getting along without such large-scale libraries and such is exceedingly doubtful.

In niche or academic worlds, you'll find a lot of Functional Programming. However, if you really want to do a large project, OOP is the only way to go.

I think that generic programming is going to come up as a new paradigm. However, it's really still in the development phase and only C++/D offer genuinely good generic programming.

Comment: OOP doesn't do any of those things. It can make them easier, but only if the design of the OO framework includes them, like in .Net, or if you are willing to write them.

Comment: Technically, you're right. However, the reality is that all popular OO languages include resource management as a feature of object orientation. You'd be hard pressed to find a directly object supporting language that doesn't include it. And the OP is clearly interested in practice, not theory.

Comment: resource management is not a feature of object orientation - resource management is a feature of imperative programming languages, which can be object oriented or not.  I don't know of any purely functional languages that force you to manage system resources explicitly.