# Design pattern for non OOP languages

Tags: design-patterns

From my understanding, OOP languages deals with abstraction, inheritance and polymorphism. Is that correct?

And my question is how can an non OOP language make use of design patterns?

Comment: what language are you developing in?

Comment: for functional programming: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/327955/does-functional-programming-replace-gof-design-patterns

Answer (score 0):

The link noted in Shawn Mclean's comment is excellent.

Design Patterns are often about OO, but they don't have to be. The original design patterns were [pattern languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pattern_language) for physical architecture.

Have a look at [Patterns in Functional Programming](http://patternsinfp.wordpress.com/) or (Real Time/embedded)[http://www.eventhelix.com/realtimemantra/patterns/] where OO is often not available.

Answer (score 0):

In C function pointers are often used to implement polymorphism, design pattern Command etc.