# Is the `Builder` design pattern obsolete in Python?

Tags: python, design-patterns, builder

I was reading through [this article on design patterns in Scala](http://www.lihaoyi.com/post/OldDesignPatternsinScala.html), and they presented the argument that the Builder pattern is relevant in Java, as it allows for code such as:

```
CarBuilder carBuilder = new CarBuilder()
carBuilder.setSeats(2)
carBuilder.setSportsCar(true)
carBuilder.setTripComputer(true)
carBuilder.setGPS(false)
Car car = carBuilder.build()
```

versus the more confusion-prone form:

```
Car car = new Car(2, true, true, false)
```

They later stated that:

> In a language like Scala which lets you name arguments while passing
>   them in, the builder pattern is mostly obsolete...

Is this a similar situation for Python, as you're able to name keyword arguments in any call, or is there some reasonable application for this design pattern?

Comment: You can pass a builder around before `build()`ing, having different aspects of initialization performed at different times and locations. Also, there may be complex logic involved in how to create an object - or even *which*. 'Fluent' APIs are often only possible through builder pattern.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

An authoritative answer can be found in the book **Effective Java**.
Chapter 2 is where the famous Java Builder pattern by Josh Bloch originates.
On page 15, it states,

> **The Builder pattern simulates named optional parameters** as found in Ada and Python.

So the answer to your question is an emphatic *yes*. There is no need to *simulate* a pattern that exists natively in a language.

You may also be interested in this popular thread: [Does functional programming replace GoF design patterns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/327955/does-functional-programming-replace-gof-design-patterns)

Answer (score 3):

As a Scala programmer I would say that this is the case. I've implemented an API where the Java code used a "Builder" while the Scala code was just regular Scala code. I belive the same could be done in Python without any hindrance and using a builder pattern is not strictly required to have that behaviour. Named parameters work way better, are more readable and usually lead to cleaner solutions.