# To what extent modern C++ obviate the need for design patterns?

Tags: c++, design-patterns

The Design Patterns book by GoF which came out in 1994 was written with C++ like languages
in mind and many of the code examples were given in C++. Programmers of other languages felt
that their languages did not need these 23 design patterns as those languages had features
that made many of the patterns redundant.

From Wikipedia:

> A primary criticism of Design Patterns is that its patterns are simply workarounds for missing features in C++, replacing elegant abstract features with lengthy concrete patterns, essentially becoming a "human compiler" or "generating by hand the expansions of some macro". Peter Norvig demonstrates that 16 out of the 23 patterns in Design Patterns are simplified or eliminated (via direct language support) in Lisp or Dylan.

C++ has undergone five revisions since the Design Patterns book came out (in 98, 03, 11, 14, 17).
So the question is, to what extent does modern C++ simplify or eliminate the need for these 23 design patterns?

It would be good to list the Design Pattern along with the C++ language feature which eliminates or simplifies the need for that Pattern.

Comment: I would say *"command"* has free implementation with `std::function` and lambda. else I would say it is basically the same.

Comment: If you mean Gemma-Helm-Johnson-Vlissides, then I find the book still relevant. However, I have not read the argument by Peter Norvig (no link?).

Comment: @KennyOstrom: Yes, that's the book. The link to Peter Norvig's argument is to be found in http://www.norvig.com/design-patterns/

Comment: I would vote this for off-topic. Since it ts based on generic algorithms. also it may be a little opinion based.

Comment: Maybe specific pattern (with implementation) is more on-topic? but it's working code...

Comment: @appleapple: Instead of asking a question for each Pattern, I felt it would be better to address all of them in one.

Comment: @user846834 the implementation in that book, IIRC, are all out-of-date. and has better alternative. the idea, however, would be unable to answer without implementation and situation.

Comment: Looks like the slides for what is probably a pretty interesting talk. Is this the right forum for an extended discussion with no right answer? Certainly some design patterns are easier in specific languages. Does that make them not patterns, or was the book done in a low level language to avoid dismissing things that are implemented for you in some higher level languages or libraries?

Comment: @KennyOstrom: My question is specific to C++ only. If GoF were to revise the book today taking into account all the revisions that C++ went through, would they eliminate any of the 23 patterns from the book because of the features included in the revisions?

Comment: @KennyOstrom: The book's authors, Erich Gamma, Richard Helm, Ralph Johnson and John Vlissides are collectively known as Gang of Four (GoF).

Comment: addressed fairly well in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/327955/does-functional-programming-replace-gof-design-patterns?rq=1

Comment: I would also suggest that Iterator is pretty thoroughly implemented in c++. Oh, and I never remember GoF. Every time. Although I usually figure it out if someone actually says "gang of four" first. :)

Comment: Creational and structural patterns are trivial thanks to smart pointers and C++17 prvalue copy elision. A singleton is just a namespace. Structural and behavioral patterns are simplified by easier template meta programming. Behaviral pattern are simplified by the inclusion of functional programming inside c++ (lambda, ...). Behavioral and structural pattern would be damned simplified if we had the dot operator or when reflexion will be standardized.

Answer (score 1):

You're right that a number of patterns aren't required now.
However, some architectural patterns like adapter are "language-insensitive" and widely used in enterprise programming to decouple layers.
Some patterns like visitor are more readable and better controlled that alternatives based on new language features.
So I think the design patterns should be revised but not discarded.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that *Design Patterns* are *concepts* which are *modelled* in a particular language using language features.

For example, as people stated in the comments, *Command pattern* can be modelled with `std::function` or any other callable.

But *models* do not make *concepts* unnecessary. *Concepts* are a very useful tool for thinking and designing, whereas *models* come in when implementing.

Comment: Sorry, missed reading this answer until now.